# Using jQuery noConflict with flowplayer tools

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, flowplayer

i appear to be in the midst of troubleshooting a namespace
conflict of the $() function.  i'm using validate 1.4.  i've attempted
to use jQuery's noConflict() method, but i'm still missing something.

```
<link href="/c/jq/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.1.2/full/
jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.ui.tabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.ui.accordion.js" type="text/javascript"></
script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    /* ]]> */
</script>
<script src="/js/cilp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/cilp/validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

if i comment out the last two external references (the validate files)
all is well.  here is the validate.js file:

$j(function($) {
    $j.extend( $.validator.messages, {
        required: 'Required'
    } );

    $j( '#qotw-form' ).validate( {
        rules: {
            'qotw-options': 'required'
        },

        submitHandler: function() {
            var answer = $j( "input[name='qotw-options']:checked" ).val();
            var correct = answer == 'c' ? true : false;
            var res = correct ? 'Correct!' : 'Try again!';
            $j( '#qotw-answer' ).html(res);
        },

        focusCleanup: true

        //, debug: true
    } );

} );
```

hopefully i'm doing something silly.  i just wish i knew an easy way
to namespace a given plugin to avoid this problem.  thanks for any
help!

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing in the value of `$` to `$j(function($) {`

You need to have something like:

```
$j(function($,$j) {
    $j.extend( $.validator.messages, {
        required: 'Required'
    } );
[...]

} )($,$j);
```

Otherwise, the `$` you pass in will always be undefined. Assuming, you are passing in the flowplayer `$` otherwise, pass in the `$j` and change the inner variable to `$j`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much with noConflict,but shouldn't this:

```
$j.extend( $.validator.messages, {
```

be

```
$j.extend( $j.validator.messages, {
```